# SQL Oracle merge 2 tables with one compound pk on one table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, merge, timestamp

I've got problem to merge 2 tables in Oracle PL/SQL.

I have `table_A` with compound primary key on columns (`pk1, pk2, pk3`)

| PK1 | PK2 | PK3 | Column1a | Column2a | TMSP1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 | 03/03/2023 09:01 PM |
| Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | 03/03/2023 09:02 PM |
| Cell 3 | Cell 3 | Cell 3 | Cell 3 | Cell 3 | 03/03/2023 09:03 PM |

`table_B` has no pk, date is unique but defined as varchar:

| TMSP2 | **ColVal1** | **ColVal2** | **ColVal3** | **ColVal4** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/03/2023 21:00 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 |
| 03/04/2023 09:02 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 |
| 03/04/2023 21:01 | Cell 3 | Cell 3 | Cell 3 | Cell 3 |

I need to use PK and merge all ColVal1/ColVal2/ColVal3/ColVal4 value from Table_B to Table_A - Table_A got with the same name new columns ColVal1/ColVal2/ColVal3/ColVal4 ready to insert from Table_B

Table_A got 3 column that makes PK, timestamp, few other columns (like Columna1a, Columna2a etc.) and all ColVal columns ready to fill

Table_B got 1 date column in varchar and all ColVal columns with values in it

- TMSP1 - timestamp in timestamp (AM/PM) every 1 min
- TMSP2 - timestamp in varchar every 12h (24hour time)

My first thought was something like that

```
MERGE INTO table_a A
USING (SELECT  
           TMSP2, 
           LEAD(TMSP2, 1) AS NXT, 
           COLVAL1, COLVAL2, COLVAL3, COLVAL4 
       FROM TABLE_B) B ON A.TMSP1 <= to_date(B.TMSP2) 
                       AND A.TMSP1 >= to_date(B.NXT)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET A.COLVAL1 = B.COLVAL2, 
            A.COLVAL1 = B.COLVAL2,
            A.COLVAL3 = B.COLAVAL3,
            A.COLVAL4 = B.COLVAL4;
```

but it executes this task for many hours and I don't get any result, I've got tip to use compound PK and try to merge it but I don't have any idea how to...

Comment: run an explain plan on the statement and post the results

Comment: `A.TMSP1<=to_date(B.TMSP2) AND A.TMSP1>=to_date(B.NXT)` is not correct. It should be something like `A.TMSP1 between to_date(B.TMSP2) AND to_date(B.NXT)` , ie `A.TMSP1>=to_date(B.TMSP2) AND A.TMSP1<=to_date(B.NXT)`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with a working example where you explain (ish, not code) the logic you are trying to implement. `table_a` has a composite primary key but you never reference that primary key and it is unclear what the relationship is between `table_a` and `table_b`. There is also the problem that `table_a` has times every minute (but how does that work when the primary key does not include the time column) and times every 12 hours in `table_b` and no obvious logic to merge them. Additionally, you try to use `a.colval1` when `table_a` does not have that column.

Comment: Calendar dates should be stored in date column (which also includes hour, minute and second). If you can't change like that, than convert to date using to_date. And I still have some doubts about a merge condition like A.TMSP1 between to_date(B.TMSP2) AND to_date(B.NXT), to what extent that would do. If you do not have to insert, then why not just use update?